# Documentum string attribute which oracle data type is?

Tags: oracle, documentum

We have Documentum 16.7 with Oracle 12.

Our supplier stands that Documentum uses fixed data type for Oracle. So I found old documents like
https://documentumsite.files.wordpress.com/2016/05/emc-documentum-content-server-7-2-system-object-refrence-guide.pdf
This part confirms:

```
DM_ STRING string,
character, char
Oracle
char(64) max
length is 4000
```

But this document is old, I cannot find more recent references.

As today there is yet this mapping?

Or modern Documentum with not so old Oracle maps with more flexible data type as VARCHAR2?

I'd like to find official documentation about latests Documentum relesaes.
(link to all official releases documentation could be usefull for anybody)

Answer (score 2):

The underlying model stays the same. This is from DCTM 21.2 Object reference:

DM_ STRING char(64) max length is 4000

You can find the documentation on Opentext's support site (requires an account):

Main Documentum documentation: https://knowledge.opentext.com/knowledge/llisapi.dll/open/66215269

Object Reference direct link (21.2): http://webapp.opentext.com/piroot/edccs/v210200/edccs-ord/en/html/_manual.htm

Comment: thx a lot. upvoted. anyway I want to go deeper before accept. The links to opentext go to restricted area, it seems it's not enough to have an account, you need customer support contract. A direct collegue who worked on DCTM says that Oracle creates Varchar2 field. In addition this link says it's Varchar created:  https://bluefishgroup.com/insights/ecm/object-types/  (...DM_STRING: Stored in Oracle as a VARCHAR max size 255 (2000 if using Oracle...)

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like accepting my answer, because I have not any official documentation to link for various versions of DCTM, anyway I can firmly say that DCTM 16.7 on Oracle 12c manages DM_STRING as VARCHAR2.

[image]